# Ionic3: Cannot access class property from inside events.subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript, events, ionic2, ionic3

I have a class that is listening for an event. When that event happens, I want to push the data coming with the even to the array and display it. This is my class:

```
export class randomClass {

  someArray:Array<string>;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
              public navParams: NavParams,
              public events: Events) {

    events.subscribe('event',
      (data) => {
        //some random code
        this.someArray.push(data); //this fails
      }
    )
  }
```

The error that I get is: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 
            '_this.communication.push')

I'm guess this is trivial but can't find the answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. The problem was that I had to initialize the property with an empty array (can somebody explain why?). The following solved the problem.

```
communication:Array<string> = [];
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem was that I had to initialize the property with an empty
>   array (**can somebody explain why?**)

When you do this

```
someArray: Array<string>;
```

You're just declaring a property called `someArray` and setting its type to be an `Array` of `strings`, **but you're not initializing that property**, so initially `someArray` will be `undefined`.

So when you try to do this:

```
this.someArray.push(data);
```

since `this.someArray` is undefined, you're trying to call the `push` method of `undefined`, which does not exist (and that's why the error says something like *TypeError: **undefined is not an object***).

Just like you've said, the solution is to initialize `someArray` with an empty `Array`. That way, you will be able to call the `push` method since it's defined in every object whose type is an `Array`.

```
someArray: Array<string> = [];
```

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that @Mike :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when transpile this code into javascript, the value of the variable `someArray` is equal to **undefined**. That how transpiler works. You cannot push data into an undefined variable. Because it is not an array. If you initialize it as `someArray:Array<string> = []` it will be transpile into a `var someArray = []`. Now you can push the data into the array.